# Generic csv parser in java

Tags: java, parsing, csv

I have a csv file with headers in order fname,mname,lname and a csv parser to parse this. I am reading the file line by line and splitting by delimitter (",") and according to index i'll get the values 0=fname, 1=mname, 2=lname.

Now again if a csv comes with headers in the order lname,fname and mname i have to change the code again. I want to write a generic parser which regardless of the order of the header stores the value in respective fields. Any  suggestions?

Comment: a quick hack way, you read the header to to an `Arraylist<String>` read the line by line .. when you look for  `fname` , get the index of it from the arraylist then you will know the index of the stored data. Agian that's just a hack. Personally create yourself an object for each Line with the appropriate headers as your deal with each line .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest not to write a generic parser and use [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/).

As you don't know the order of the columns, use CSVFormat as described in its documentation:

> **Referencing columns safely**
>
> If your source contains a header record, you can simplify your code
>   and safely reference columns, by using [withHeader(String...)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.html#withHeader(java.lang.String...)) with no
>   arguments:
>
> `CSVFormat.EXCEL.withHeader();`
>
> This causes the parser to read the first record and use its values as
>   column names. Then, call one of the [CSVRecord](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVRecord.html) get method that takes a
>   String column name argument:
>
> `String value = record.get("Col1");`
>
> This makes your code impervious to changes in column order in the CSV
>   file.

Comment: I went through this, but i think even in this we have to declare the CSVFormat first i mean the order of headers. I dont want to declare this as i dont know in which order the fields will come. I only know what fields. Any other option?

Comment: `CSVFormat` precisely allows you to reference columns without knowing their order. See my edit.